# Filter Apple Calendar by Calendar

Tags: calendar

Is there any way of searching or filtering the Apple Calendar app by Calendar name? I would like to see ONLY the events for one calendar.

Answer (score 2):

The left-side panel allows you to toggle calendars off and on, so you can just turn off the ones you're hiding, and toggle on the one you want to see.

If that panel is hidden it's controlled by the mini-calendar icon on the top left of the Calendar window, or under the View menu as "Show Calendar List".

Comment: Exactly, but then you have to scroll through the calendar to find the events one by one. I've reworded the question to make it clearer.